# SSIS Power query connection manager error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, powerquery

I install SQL Server Connector for Power Query for SQL server 2017. Create SSDT SSIS package with power query connector. It works perfect in SSDT! But when I deploy project to SSIS catalog, I get an error:

> Credentials are required to connect web source.

> Package:Error: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

Moreover, when I import this package from SSIS catalog to new project, power query connection manager go away from project with error:

> The connection "{EFC6889A-D312-4A9E-B251-877C7A67B8DF}" is not found.
> This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!! In SSDT I used my own login. But in SSIS catalog used SSIS proxy account that don't have access to web.
After granting access to web to SSIS proxy account it works!

If you met same error just try to run SSDT under proxy account and check web access in data source manager :)